# Help with making out handwriting-like engraving on a silver cigarette case

Tags: german-to-english, handwriting

Bought a silver cigarette case with this engraved on it:

[image]

I tried to translate it myself, but I don't know the language at all and couldn't really match up any letters.

I believe it's German because the case has a German Silver hallmark.

Answer (score 19):

It is German and the second line is written in [Kurrent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurrent).
The first line is written in "normal" script, which implies a name, personal or local.

The first line reads

> Pfann Hptm
>   *[Pfann Cptn.]*

Hptm is the abbreviation of Hauptmann which is Captain.

The second line is

> Kriegsjahr 1914 - 16
>   *[Year of war 1914 - 16]*

**EDIT:**
As asked in the comments: according to the german [Wikipedia article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Kurrentschrift) it was usual for some special fields like names or headings to use the "normal" script (*lateinische Schreibschrift*) parallel to *Kurrent* for the remaining text.

**EDIT 2:**
As supposed in the comments here the *Hptm* writtein in Kurrent:

[image: Hptm written in Kurrent]

One can sense or assume that this abbreviation is written in a mix of Kurrent and latin Schreibschrift. The **H** is similar to Kurrent, the **p** rather unclear, the **t** latin Schreibschrift and the **m** is almost the same in Kurrent and Schreibschrift.

Comment: How about explaining in this answer why "normal script" implies a name? How Kurrent and normal differ here (or even in general)? Perhaps a more Schönschrift example für "Pfann-Hptm"?

Comment: @LangLangC What do you mean with "a more Schönschrift example"?

Comment: Transliterate the proposed Hptm to a standard example either with an appropriate font or manually. I find the reasoning reasonable, but optically unconvincing. I want to read Hptm, I can see how that might make sense to read Hptm but I can not read nor see Hptm there. Since also the P in Pfann is quite freestylish I think the whole thing might benefit from a comparison to highly standardised "and that's how it was supposed to look in a nice school".

Comment: Presumably Herr Pfann inscribed it himself, in which case it would take on characteristics of a personal signature, which can depart radically from normal handwriting conventions.

Comment: Wieso ist h in Hptm. klein geschrieben? Wieso steht der militärische Rang hinter dem Namen und nicht davor (Hauptm. Pfann)? War Hptm. überhaupt eine gängige Abkürzung für Hauptmann zu der Zeit? Wieso ist Pfannhptm. zusammengeschrieben? Wieso fehlt der Abkürzg. der Punkt?

Comment: @userunknown Hptm ist nicht klein geschrieben, das ist das große H in Kurrent. Den militärische Rang nach dem Namen zu nennen ist nach meinem Kenntnisstand nicht unüblich. Die Abkürzung liefert bei einer Internetsuche viele Quellen für diese Zeit - also: ja ist üblich. Die Abkürzung des Rangs ohne Punkt habe ich auch schon oft gesehen, ist wohl auch üblich/möglich. Der fehlende Zwischenraum oder der geringe Abstand ist in der Tat merkwürdig, aber vermutlich schwerlich zu erklären.

Comment: Dein vorgestelltes groß H hat aber eine Unterlänge am Ende, gefolgt von der Unterlänge des p, während die Gravur nur eine Unterlänge hat. Auch weise ich den Versuch zurück, den fehlenden Zwischenraum zu einem geringen umzuetikettieren. Da ist kein geringer Zwischenraum, sondern keiner. Wäre Pfann jetzt ein so häufiger Nachname wie Meier, Müller, Schulz, dann könnte ich das Sich-Klammern an diese Interpretation ja etwas nachvollziehen. So halte ich es für großen Pfusch.

Answer (score 7):

Could the first line be "Pfann Hptm"? Pfann is a surname, and Hptm is the abbreviation for Hauptmann (captain).